# Interpreting Hidden Code

Tags: lua, decoding

I'm trying to see what this file has inside of it (written in L u a) for a game I play, so that I can learn and see how it is done. But at the beginning it has functions defined that make everything unreadable - The code is in the file.

And as the code goes on you get more "prettified" coding with ###. Could someone tell me how to make it so it is readable again?

Comment: It seems that this code is deliberately obfuscated in order to make it hard to read. So you'll not have much luck here.

Comment: This doesn't seem valid Lua code: those backslashes (\\) at the end of the first dozen lines are suspect. Are you sure those backslashes are present in the original code? Or maybe you did cut&paste with the output of an editor, a browser or some other program you used to visualize the file?

Comment: Maybe a link to the whole file could help.

Comment: Those backslashes are just characters specified in octal AFAIR.

Comment: @Caladan No. \ddd *inside* a Lua string are [characters expressed in *decimal*](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#3.1) (unlike C), but I didn't refer to those. *At the end* of the first lines of the posted code there are backslashes. Some are inside strings, but they escape hard newlines, which in itself is strange., but there are backslashes even outside strings, which makes the code illegal (e.g. between `gsub` and the next open `(`).

Comment: @Caladan It seems that either that code is meant to be preprocessed before being executed or that the OP has altered something in the copy-paste operation.

Comment: Ok, I see which you mean. You're probably right that those got here by an accident.

Comment: @Jonathan If you want to thank someone upvote or accept his answers. This helps keep SO an high-quality environment. :-)

Comment: I've rollbacked the question to remove the thanks, that's not really necessary in SO, gain some reputation (only 5 more) and upvote the answers is the SO way to say thanks.

Comment: Why did the obfuscated code and other info get edited out of the question? It makes the question less clear on what's being asked without it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your [file](http://www.filedropper.com/mm_1) contains a block of compressed code between `[===[` and `]===]`. The compression is just a [dictionary coder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictionary_coder), where keywords are mapped to individual byte values. The decompression is done via `prettify` (see Lorenzo's post).

Running the compressed code through `prettify` gives you [this code](http://pastebin.com/zPDKg6t6) (compression ratio ~46%), which happens to be *another* decompression routine! In fact, it appears to be an minimized version of [this code](http://math2.org/luasearch-2/luadist-extract/compress_deflatelua-0.1.0.dist/module/lmod/compress/deflatelua.lua).

That "ungzip" routine is then used to process another ~150KB string contained in the file, which expands into 675KB of text.

Believe or not, that text is *also* compressed, via the same scheme as the ungzip code, and contains its *own* copy of `prettify`. Running that text through its `prettify` gives us the final 963KB of Lua, which is then executed.

Here's the [final, decompressed code](http://codetidy.com/6500/), posted to the first site I found that would allow a 963KB upload. The formatting is just as it comes out of `prettify`.

Comment: Really nice find! :-)

Comment: @Jonathan Now that I've seen the original file I understand the presence of all those backslashes: the original file is encoded in UTF-8, and probably you opened the file using another encoding and that messed-up the copy-paste procedure.

Comment: Thank you very much! Indeed a very nice find, and thank you both for helping me! :)

Comment: @Jonathan IMO you should have accepted Mud's answer, since it is more precise and to the point, although less detailed. I'm new on SO so I don't know if you can change your choice or what is SO policy in these cases.

Comment: Oh I wasn't aware you could only accept one. Thanks for letting me know... I did switch it. Though I do appreciate your answers too.

Comment: You can only accept one, but you can upvote many, although you need at least 15 rep to upvote ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I'm the author of the utility, [Squish](http://matthewwild.co.uk/projects/squish/), that was used to create that file.

Some of Squish's filters are reversible, some are not. Here is a tip for reversing as much as possible as easily as possible:

At the top of the file, paste this code snippet:

```
local _ls = loadstring;
function loadstring(...)
    local f = assert(io.open("unsquished.lua", "w+"));
    f:write((...));
    f:close();
    return _ls(...)
end
```

Then run the file with Lua. It will generate a new file, `unsquished.lua`, in the current directory. This file is now 100% pure Lua.

However you won't find it particularly easy to read, as all unnecessary whitespace will have been stripped, and some variable names replaced by short alternatives. You could look at [lunadry](https://github.com/batrick/lunadry) to reformat the code, but the original variable names are irretrievable.

Also, the file contains multiple modules merged into one. You will see these looking like:

```
package.preload['modulename']=(function(...)
    --code here--
end)
```

You can split these back out into separate files if you want to, to help with readability.

Hope this helps!

**Edit:** Be careful using this technique on files you don't trust, as it will actually execute them as you run it. Not a good idea if you don't already know what they do!

Answer (score 2):

Since the posted code is not complete, and probably messed-up, mine are only educated guesses.

It seems that the whole code stores, in the variable `ungz`, the result of a call to an "anonymous function": the `(function ()` fragment probably is closed somewhere like this:

```
ungz = (function()   -- "anonymous function"
    -- ...
    -- definition of `prettify` + helper data
    -- ...
    return assert( loadstring(
        prettify [===[
            ...obfuscated code in this long string...
        ]===]
    ) )  -- end of `loadstring` and of `assert` calls

end)()   --<<-- note the () to call the "anonymous function"
```

Inside this function you may see the definition of the function `prettify` with its helper data, which can be reformatted for better understanding in this way:

```
local base_char,keywords=128, {
    "and","break","do","else","elseif","end","false","for",
    "function","if","in","local","nil","not","or","repeat","return",
    "then","true","until","while","read","nbits","nbits_left_in_byte",
    "wnd_pos","output","val","input",}; 
function prettify(code) 
    return code:gsub( 
        "["..string.char(base_char).."-"..string.char(base_char+#keywords).."]",
        function (c) 
            return keywords[c:byte()-base_char]; 
        end
    ) 
end
```

The function `prettify`, when applied to a string, will return the same string where any character having a numeric code in the range `base_char`-`base_char+#keywords` is replaced with a keyword of the `keyword` list.

This is used to "deobfuscate" the "obfuscated" code using `assert(loadstring(prettify[===[xxxx]===]))` where I indicated the obfuscated code as `xxxx`.

**Addendum:** note that applying `prettify` to the fragment `[===[xxxx]===]` doesn't give back meaningful code (a `base_char` value of `202` would give better results, although not perfect). Moreover you have to merge all the lines inside that long string and substitute it with a normal string, i.e. turn it to `"yyyy"`, where `yyyy` is `xxxx` with all hard newlines removed.

Probably all that code is preprocessed in some further way.